# Как понимать "профилактика пожарной безопасности"?

Tags: значение-слов, словосочетания

Сегодня в метро услышал словосочетание:

- *профилактика пожарной безопасности*

если посмотреть определение слова *профилактика* в Викисловаре, увидим следующее:

> совокупность действий, мероприятий, направленных на предупреждение, предотвращение чего-либо нежелательного, опасного, вредного

или попробовать заменить синонимом:

- *предупреждение пожарной безопасности*

то получается несуразица. Можно сказать *профилактика пожаров* или *профилактика преступности*, но как понять (чисто формально) выражение, приведённое в начале?

Answer (score 3):

Нельзя. Это частая ошибка - с пожарами, противопожарами и безопасностью - с их комбинацией.

Надо: [ПОЖАРНАЯ ПРОФИЛАКТИКА И ПРОТИВОПОЖАРНАЯ ЗАЩИТА](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc_colier/6383/%D0%9F%D0%9E%D0%96%D0%90%D0%A0%D0%9D%D0%90%D0%AF)

> **ПОЖАРНАЯ ПРОФИЛАКТИКА**
>
> Ответственные органы и их обязанности. Пожарная профилактика
>   традиционно ограничивалась обучением технике безопасности и мерами по
>   предупреждению пожаров и всегда входила в обязанности муниципальных
>   управлений пожарной охраны. Сегодня круг мероприятий по пожарной
>   профилактике расширен, и в него вошли проверка и утверждение проектов
>   строительства, контроль за выполнением норм по пожарной безопасности,
>   борьба с поджогами (в т.ч. с пожароопасными играми подростков), сбор
>   данных, а также инструктаж и обучение широкой общественности и
>   специальных контингентов. Задачи пожарной профилактики можно разделить
>   на три широких, но тесно связанных комплекса мероприятий: 1) обучение,
>   в т.ч. распространение знаний о пожаробезопасном поведении (о
>   необходимости установки домашних индикаторов задымленности и хранения
>   зажигалок и спичек в местах, недоступных детям); 2) пожарный надзор,
>   предусматривающий разработку государственных норм пожарной
>   безопасности и строительных норм, а также проверку их выполнения; 3)
>   обеспечение оборудованием и технические разработки (установка
>   переносных огнетушителей и изготовление зажигалок безопасного
>   пользования). Из трех перечисленных комплексов мероприятий сложнее
>   всего, по-видимому, пожарный надзор. В сферу надзора включены нормы
>   пожарной профилактики, строительные пожарные нормы и правила,
>   стандарты изготовления и установки противопожарного оборудования и
>   стандарты пожарной безопасности на товары широкого потребления.
>
> **ПРОТИВОПОЖАРНАЯ ЗАЩИТА**
>
> Мероприятия по противопожарной защите включают: 1) контроль
>   материалов, продуктов и оборудования; 2) активное ограничение
>   распространения огня с использованием средств пожарной сигнализации,
>   систем автоматического пожаротушения и переносных огнетушителей; 3)
>   устройство пассивных систем, ограничивающих распространение огня,
>   дыма, жара и газов за счет секционирования помещений; 4) эвакуацию
>   людей из горящего здания в безопасное место.

Ещё смотрим: [Основы пожарной профилактики](http://studopedia.ru/view_ohranatruda.php?id=54); [Пожарная профилактика и противопожарные мероприятия](http://www.metal-tehdoor.ru/articles/pozharnaya-profilaktika-i-protivopozharnee-meropriyatiya.html).

А пожарную безопасность *обеспечивают* ([Обеспечение пожарной безопасности](http://base.garant.ru/10103955/4/)).

Весёлое на десерт:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Да, здесь логическая ошибка: профилактика - это упреждающие меры по недопущению чего-то. Здесь вышло, что борются с безопасностью. Можно сказать "профилактика (=профилактические меры) в интересах пожарной безопасности".

Answer (score 1):

Да нормальное выражение.
И чисто формально, и по сути выражение, приведённое в начале темы, понять легко, если не спешить с употреблением формального синонима, а вспомнить, что кроме профилактики *гриппа* (как частный пример) есть ещё и общая профилактика *здоровья*. То есть правомерно считать, что профилактика (в медицине) как система мер по предупреждению болезней, по сохранению здоровья и продлению жизни человека, или как предупредительные меры (в технике) для поддержания технического объекта в исправном или работоспособном состоянии (ремонт, чистка, смазка и т. п.) означает работу как против негативного будущего (болезни, поломки), так и за позитивное настоящее (здоровье, исправность). Профилактика болезней, профилактика организма, здоровья, профилактика отказов, профилактика оборудования.

К нашему случаю. Во избежание пожара на каком-то объекте следует спроектировать и провести соответствующие организационно-технические мероприятия, именно — технически, технологически и физически реализовать, построить, соорудить и т. п. комплекс, в котором соответствующим образовать нормировать: а) содержание и хранение горючих материалов, б) технологию проведения огневых работ (если они могут быть), в) наличие и размещение средств контроля, сигнализации, пожаротушения, г) систему оповещения и связи, д) подготовку специалистов, распределение ответственности, е) планы эвакуации людей и ценностей... и пр. и т. п...

Вот это в целом и называется системой пожарной безопасности. Пока такая система не будет внедрена и принята пожарной инстанцией, ни один объект к эксплуатации допущен не будет — ни завод, ни торговый киоск. Чтобы эта система оставалась живой и постоянно готовой к действию, нужно планово проводить её профилактику: осмотры, замены, ремонты, модернизации и т. п. 
Так что обсуждаемое в теме выражение вполне корректно: *профилактика пожарной безопасности*.
Что? — Профилактика. А что это такое? — Это работа, деятельность, плановый мониторинг. Мониторинг — чего? — Системы безопасности. Какой по назначению? — Пожарной. А что это такое? — Организационный и технический комплекс.

Есть ещё профилактика электротравматизма (это как себя вести на электрообъектах). И есть профилактика электробезопасности. Это немножко шире.