# Не принимаю выражение "противопожарная безопасность"

Tags: грамотная-речь, терминология

Сегодня на канале Россия 1 Э. Маркявичус, упоминая о ТРАГЕДИИ в Кемерово, выражает озабоченность о "противопожарной безопасности".
Обучите, пожалуйста, дикторов центральных каналов элементарным понятиям о безопасности. Может обеспечить жизнь и здоровье людей только "Пожарная безопасность!"

Comment: Давайте не будем митинговать. Здесь и вообще.

Comment: См. также: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/419836/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8

Comment: @М_Г Мне кажется, что **Россия** 1 требует или выделения кавычками, или шрифтом; и - Эрнест **Мацкявичюс**. Был ещё похожий вопрос: "Что такое противопожарная защита?" [закрыт] https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/429726/Что-такое-противопожарная-защита

Answer (score 1):

> [Вопрос № 200785](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=200785%20%20%20%20)
>    Здравствуйте! Поясните, пожалуйста, как правильно говорить и почему именно так: "Пожарная безопасность" или "Противопожарная безопасность". Заранее благодарю!
>   Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>   Правильно: *пожарная безопасность*, что означает «безопасность от пожара».

В официальных документах — **пожарная** безопасность.

> Приказ МЧС РФ от 18.06.2003 N 313 "Об утверждении Правил пожарной безопасности в Российской Федерации (ППБ 01-03)"  (http://www.consultant.ru/document/cons_doc_LAW_43497/0b93cc757b53bbc86c687d43202078da6ee812d4/)
>
> Федеральный закон "О пожарной безопасности" (http://www.consultant.ru/document/cons_doc_LAW_5438/)

В то же время в Нацкопрусе нашлось 69 вхождений, где безопасность — **противопожарная** (?!).

> [Противопожарная безопасность](http://insafety.ru/article/pp.php)
>   «Противопожарная безопасность» - некорректное словосочетание для обозначения «пожарной безопасности».
>   Пожарная безопасность - это состояние защищенности населения, объектов народного хозяйства и иного назначения, а также окружающей природной среды от опасных факторов и воздействий пожара (ГОСТ Р 22.0.05-94) и/или состояние защищенности личности, имущества, общества и государства от пожаров (ГОСТ Р 12.3.047-98)
>   Зачастую в печати и в обиходе встречаются случаи использования словосочетания «противопожарная безопасность». 
>   Как показывает практика, многие специалисты считают, что словосочетания «пожарная безопасность» и «противопожарная безопасность» имеют равнозначное значение, однако это не так. 
>   Словосочетание «пожарная безопасность» введено Федеральным законом «О пожарной безопасности» как состояние защищенности личности, имущества, общества и государства от пожаров. Словосочетание «противопожарная безопасность» в нормативных правовых актах и нормативных документах по пожарной безопасности не встречается, поэтому представляется затруднительным определить его значение.
>   Таким образом использовать словосочетание «противопожарная безопасность» некорректно.
>
> Стоит отметить, что слово «противопожарный» используется часто в нормативных правовых актах и нормативных документах по пожарной безопасности, но с другими словами: «**противопожарный разрыв**», «**противопожарная преграда**», «**противопожарный режим»**,»**противопожарная защита**» и другие.